# Running a `SELECT` for a range of dates to populate a table

Tags: sql, for-loop, select, stored-procedures, sap-ase

I have a (somewhat elaborate) `SELECT` statement, which extracts for a specific date a subset of rows from a table, based on a specific time stamp. Naively, something like

```
SELECT id, runTime
  FROM ...
...
 WHERE runTime < @MyTime
```

where `@MyTime` is some date-time parameter. I need to run that `SELECT` for a long range of consecutive dates (from June 1, to November 1 of this year, say), storing the result in a `MyOutTable` which has already been created, with fields `id`, `runTime`, `controlDate`, where `controlDate` is the value of the date used to retrieve the id and `runTime` from my table.

Is there a short way to do this in SQL avoiding using Python? Say have some stored procedure which takes start and end date parameters and generates needed data, populating the output table?

Thank you very much

Comment: you mean `controlDate` is @MyTime?

Comment: @shockwave yes, but i need a range of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MyOutTable ( ControlDate, id, runTime )
SELECT '2017-10-30' as ControlDate, id, runTime
FROM ...
...
WHERE runTime < @MyTime
```

Note there is no `VALUES` keyword, and the `ControlDate` value is a constant literal, though you could also use `CURDATE()` or similar here.

Comment: yes, but i need a range of control dates, not just 1

Comment: And how will you know the correct date for a specific original record?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. There are a range of `controlDate`, I need a table for each one of them, from June 1 to November 1.

Comment: Then you generate a numbers table, use DATEADD() to project the numbers to the dates you need, and join that to your `SELECT`

Comment: I found a ton of ways to generate an integer list in SQL Server, but none of them work in Sybase -- do you know how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with the date/times and use `join` logic:

```
select d.dte, . . .
from (select cast('2017-06-01' as datetime) as dte union all
      select cast('2017-06-02' as datetime) as dte union all
      . . .
     ) d join
     . . .
     on runTime < d.dte;
```

Comment: this way i have to write roughly 150 selects in the internal select, any way to automate that taking all dates from `2017-06-01` to `2017-11-01`?

Comment: @gt6989b . . . For Sybase, I don't know.  You can use a calendar table.  In SQL Server, you can use a recursive CTE.  Perhaps Sybase has a different trick.